# Position Div onclick on another div with Multiple instances on a page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my problem http://jsfiddle.net/shoppyonline/re6r7/

I'm trying to get .req_menu to show on each row its clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result that you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/2c2YJ/

I removed the CSS on .rec_menu so it's not absolute, and also updated the jQuery selector to match the correct .rec_menu div and not all of them.

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dZmEj/

Comment: Not quite @McHerbie. .rec_menu is suppose to be a menu with options in it. The div should appear above the table.

Comment: Well in that case, you can keep the CSS in there. The code should be showing the correct .rec_menu now since it's matching the right div.

Comment: Thank you @McHerbie. The thing is that .req_menu is actually a drop-down menu that appears just slightly below the clicked on .req_btn. You are almost there. Can you position the .req_menu please?

Comment: I am new to Fiddle, so I keep forking the code to save it... Here is an updated example that positions the rec_menu. Likely you'll need to tweak it a bit to be exactly what you want, but here goes: http://jsfiddle.net/dZmEj/

Comment: Thank you very much @McHerbie. So how do I get .req_menu to appear just above its parent .req_btn? I mean how do I get the position of each .req_btn and place the .req_menu right below it or on top?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute position and calculate relative offset and position next to it.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

get the offset values// and use

jquery .css left values to position next to it.

Comment: Yes thank you but how do I do that for each of the .req_btns?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the height of your .rec_btns is 0, so it's not clickable.

Add `overflow: auto` to .rec_btns, the anchor inside it is a float.